# Why is the step property in a balancing network defined as it is?

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing

I was trying to understand why the equation $y_i = \left( \frac{n}{w} \right) + (i \pmod w) $ describes the step property in a balancing network?

First, recall $x_i$ to be the number of tokens a network gets as input and similarly $y_i$ to be the number of output tokens. Recall that a balancing network is just a network that distributes tokens to its output.

I was reading the art of multicore programming and in page 272 it says:

> If the number of tokens n is a multiple of four (the network width),
>   then the same number of tokens emerges from each wire. If there is one
>   excess token, it emerges on output wire 0, if there are two, they
>   emerge on output wires 0 and 1, and so on. In general,
>
> $$ n = \sum x_i $$
>
> then
>
> $$y_i = \left( \frac{n}{w} \right) + (i \pmod w) $$
>
> we call this property the **step property**.

It also defines equivalent ways to see the step property as:

1. For any $i<j$, $0 \leq y_i - y_j \leq 1$

i.e. as we go up the output wires, the wire can only increase one step at a time or not increase (so top values are always larger or equal). An example:

[image]

However, the formula $y_i = \left( \frac{n}{w} \right) + (i \pmod w) $ doesn't make sense to me also, specifically the following doesn't make sense:

> if there are two, they emerge on output wires 0 and 1, and so on...

I tried plugging in the numbers too say, $ n = 6 $, but the results don't quite make sense.

For example according to the formula above we get:

$$ y_0 = \left( \frac{6}{4} \right) + (0 \pmod 4) = 1 + 0 = 1 $$
$$ y_1 = \left( \frac{6}{4} \right) + (1 \pmod 4) = 1 + 1 = 2 $$
$$ y_2 = \left( \frac{6}{4} \right) + (2 \pmod 4) = 1 + 2 = 3 $$
$$ y_3 = \left( \frac{6}{4} \right) + (2 \pmod 4) = 1 + 3 = 4 $$

which doesn't agree with what  the picture of the diagram would be because it seems to be backwards. Not sure if I made a mistake or misunderstood the formula, but it should be giving something as in the figure/diagram/picture from the book. Also, according to the formula, is it ever possible for it be equal? It seems to always increase in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3):

The formula is wrong. The correct formula is
$$
y_i = \lfloor \frac{n}{w} \rfloor + [i < (n \mod{w})],
$$
where $[C]$ equals 1 if $C$ holds, and 0 otherwise.

Sometimes books contain mistakes. When you see a mistake, correct it and proceed. No need to ask us for permission.

Comment: thanks again! Sometimes, when Im confused or just learning a new concept, I can't tell if I'm confused, wrong or have a severe misunderstanding. Hence, my question. :) Also, did you meant i - m I believe, not sure what < would do here...

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote. I also explained the semantics of $<$.